# open source social network allowing advertising

Tags: open-source

I want to build up a social network, targeted to a specific interest. I want to generate revenues in form of ads. I first thought of building it from scratch, which will take a lot of time (even if it's something simple), then i remembered there are open source options like Diaspora or Friendica. I don't know if there are others... My question is, with these previously mentioned projects or any other, ¿is it possible to legally generate revenues?

Diaspora license is: AGPLv3,[3][4] some parts dual-licensed under MIT License[5] as well

Friendica: AGPL

¡Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **[about]**  legally generating revenues

Comment: Any idea where or should be?

Comment: I actually got here redirected from Software Recommendations. I am pretty kinda lost of where should this question belong.

Comment: AFAIK none of the GPL licenses forbids you to earn money with the software. However, the AGPL requires you to offer the source code to your users on reasonable terms. The real problem is acquiring and retaining users. Assuming you use Diaspora: why should users choose your server with ads when they could choose one without ads? Assuming you extend the code of your server: you cannot legally prevent others from also using your added code in their competing servers.

Comment: @gnat [The proposal for a software licensing stackexchange on area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58715/open-source-licensing) was closed explicitly because licensing questions are on-topic on programmers.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. @Philipp - yes, some license questions are on-topic.  However, this question is overly broad in license considerations and doesn't present an actual problem.  It's a research question that could be very simply answered by looking at the FAQs provided by the FSF on the GPL, LGPL, and AGPL.

Comment: @Philipp Glen nailed it - the way how question is spelled reads that it's not about licensing at all. There is legal and revenue and frameworks and whole bunch of stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the AGPL and the MIT license only address redistribution and have no restrictions at all regarding how you use the software. Neither forbids any form of commercial activity.

The only restriction is that the AGPL forces you to publish any code changes you make. So when you change the software to add support for displaying advertisement, you will have to publish these changes.